# Kungsleden (Sweden King's Trail) cabins in mid-June?

Tags: hiking, sweden, outdoor-activities, opening-hours

Are the cabins along the King's Trail likely to be open in mid-June (around June 20) this year? I'm specifically interested in the stretch from Ammarnäs to Hemavan. (My guidebook says they usually open in "late June".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2016, the cabins in that area will open on **June 23**, according to the Hemavan Tourist Office:

> Hi David,
>
> They open a few days later that month, the 23 of june so if you can wait a few more days it is not a bad idea.
>   Before that it can still be a lot of snow and/or very wet in the terrain so we recommend people to walk after midsummer, usually it is better conditions then.
>
> Best regards / Med vänlig hälsning

Further north (Abisko to Kebnekaise), the cabins actually open a few days earlier:

> The huts [near Abisko] open on June 17th. Temperatures have been really high the last weeks so chances are that the trail will be snow-free even in higher altitudes by the time the huts open. However, I would recommend contacting fjallbokning@stfturist.se for more information.